# How I print multiple level in gridview

Tags: gridview, printing, devexpress, view, multi-level

I want to print report with main view and a level. The sample gridview is attachment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZHfW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [GridView.OptionsPrint.PrintDetails property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsPrint_PrintDetailstopic) to True. From there, you can use the standard print/preview/export features of the GridControl. See: [Export and Printing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument115790)